# Keyboard bugs after first letter in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my first activity when i select the text edit the keyboards appears.
When i write one letter the page scrolls as if the edit text had lost focus (but it didn't) and keyboard stay displayed even if it is not there (if i click approximately on the edit text under the displayed keyboard the keyboard entrance animation start again and everything works). I don't know what to do, look's really like a bug to me. Oh and, the bug only appears on this activity (the first activity to start), **Android 8.1** 
Code and screens : 
[Edit text before bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJMNU.png)
[Ghost keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwZVb.png) (you see it but it is not there, if i click the home button then come back, the keyboard disapeared and i can interract with the button and edit text under)
LoginActivity.java:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText e;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final Button b = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    e = findViewById(R.id.name_input);

    //if i click button or enter get to nex activity
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validate();
        }
    });

    e.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                validate();
                return true;
            }
            return false; // i don't know android that much, but i don't think there is a problem here
        }
    });

    //testing purpose
    e.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "LOST FOCUS"); //Never called
            } else {
                Log.e("ERROR", "GOT FOCUS");
            }
        }
    });

    //For the ui style, commenting it changes nothing
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

    final int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility)  {
            if((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

@Override protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


}

private void validate() {
    if (!e.getText().toString().isEmpty() && e.getText().toString().length() < 16) {
        SharedInfos.setName(e.getText().toString());
        Log.e("Name : ", e.getText().toString());

        Intent activityLaunch = new Intent(this, PresentationActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(activityLaunch);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Name must be not empty and less than 16 char long !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

activity_main.xml (layout)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".LoginActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="343dp"
    android:layout_height="336dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="Cat"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@color/accent_material_dark_1"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startButton"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
    android:text="@string/app_then"
    android:textColor="@color/accent_material_dark_1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/name_input"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/name_input" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name_input"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
    android:hint="@string/field_name"
    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
    android:textColor="@color/accent_material_dark_1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/startButton"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />
```

Comment: Just a note-  your key listener won't work.  Most keyboards don't send actual key events, most send input connection calls.  So your key event listener will never be called.

Comment: android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboardHidden" Try to configChanges on your activity in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, it was not related to the code or android. I'm using a Xiomi phone and on the internet it is advised to disable the MIUI Optimisation in the dev options when coding. It was the issue, re-enabling it and rebooting the phone solved the problem. Thanks for the answers !